# How to use emacs packages in emacs lisp scripting

Tags: batch-mode, script

I have the following emacs script f[rom here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879746/idiomatic-batch-processing-of-text-in-emacs)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/emacs --script
;;; rcat --- cat
;;; Commentary:
;;; cat function in elisp

;;; Code:

;;-*- mode: emacs-lisp;-*-

(defun process (string)
  "Just reverse the STRING."
  (concat (nreverse (string-to-list string))))

(condition-case nil
    (let (line)
      ;;commented out b/c not relevant for `cat`, but potentially useful
      (princ "argv is ")
      (princ argv)
      (princ "\n")
      (princ "command-line-args is" )
      (princ command-line-args)
      (princ "\n")

      (while (setq line (read-from-minibuffer ""))
        (princ (process line))
        (princ "\n")))
  (error nil))

(provide 'rcat)
;;; rcat ends here
```

It works well but I want to use [the s package](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) for string manipulation, and convert my script to this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/emacs --batch
;;; rcat --- cat
;;; Commentary:
;;; reverse lines cat function in elisp

;;; Code:

;;-*- mode: emacs-lisp;-*-
(require 's)

(condition-case nil
    (let (line)
      ;;commented out b/c not relevant for `cat`, but potentially useful
      (princ "argv is ")
      (princ argv)
      (princ "\n")
      (princ "command-line-args is" )
      (princ command-line-args)
      (princ "\n")

      (while (setq line (read-from-minibuffer ""))
        (princ (s-reverse line))
        (princ "\n")))
  (error nil))

(provide 'rcat)
;;; rcat ends here
```

The first code works well:

```
./rcat 1 2 3 4 < stuff.txt                           
argv is (1 2 3 4)
command-line-args is(/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD-5583e64_1/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -scriptload ./rcat 1 2 3 4)
dcba
4321
```

But executing the second, I get:

```
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, s
```

I'm not sure if using cask, batch-mode or something should work.

Comment: Make sure you take the time to read through https://swsnr.de/blog/2014/08/12/emacs-script-pitfalls/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell Emacs where to find the `s` library:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/s/")
```

Or if you put `s` in the same directory:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path ".")
```

Answer (score 3):

`--batch` doesn't process your init file, so it has no idea where your personal libraries are.

Instead of `(require 's)` (which, as per clemera's answer, means you need to set `load-path`), you could simply `(load "path/to/s.elc")` for any library you need (or `s.el` if it's not byte-compiled; or just `s` for Emacs to pick the most appropriate extension automatically).

Comment: Loading it directly gives `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "Is a directory" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")`

Comment: You have to load the `.elc` or `.el` file.  I've edited the answer to make that more obvious.  You can leave off the extension (as I'd done originally), but it's still the elisp file you need to indicate; not the containing directory.